# Django BaseDataTableView - filter_queryset method not work

Tags: jquery, django

I am using BaseDatatableView and DataTable jquery. I've already written several views for BaseDatatableView and there were no problems until I had to override the 'prepare_results' and 'render_column' methods. I need to present the results of instance methods in a table, so I overwrite the methods of the BaseDatatableView class.

This is my code in views.py

```
class MyModelDatatable(BaseDatatableView):
    model = MyModel
    columns = ['field1', 'field2', 'id']
    columns_searched = [col for col in columns if col != 'id']
    
    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        print('test')  # not displayed
        search_text = self.request.GET.get('search[value]', None)
        if search_text:
            search_terms = search_text.split()
            query = Q()

            for col in self.columns_searched:
                or_conditions = Q()

                for term in search_terms:
                    or_conditions |= Q(**{f'{col}__icontains': term})

                query |= or_conditions    

            qs = qs.filter(query)

        return qs

    def prepare_results(self, qs):
        data = []
        for item in qs:
            item_str = str(item)
            data.append({

                'field1': item_str,
                'field2': item.field2,
                'id': item.id
            })

        return data

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'field2':
            return row.field2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        return super(OrderDatatable, self).render_column(row, column)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_json_response()

    def get_json_response(self):
        draw = int(self.request.GET.get('draw', 1))
        total_records = self.get_initial_queryset().count()
        total_display_records = total_records
        start = int(self.request.GET.get('start', 0))
        length = int(self.request.GET.get('length', 10))
        end = start + length
        data = self.prepare_results(self.get_initial_queryset()[start:end])
        response = {
            'draw': draw,
            'recordsTotal': total_records,
            'recordsFiltered': total_display_records,
            'data': data,
        }

        return JsonResponse(response)
```

objDatatable.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const table = $('#my-datatable').DataTable({
        'columns': [

            {'data': 'field1'},
            {'data': 'field2'},
            {
                'data': 'id',
                'render': function (data, type, row) {
                    let actionButtons = `
                        <a  href='/edit/${data}'
                            class="btn btn-datatable btn-icon btn-transparent-dark me-2">
                            <i data-feather="edit"></i>
                        </a>
                    `;
                    return actionButtons;
                }
            },
    
        ],
        'paging': true,
        'pageLength': 20,
        'lengthMenu': [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200],
        'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': 'orders_datatable_search/',
       
        }
    });
    table.on('draw.dt', function () {
        feather.replace();
    })
});
```

With standard class fields without method overrides, filtering works correctly. After overwriting, everything works as it should, including pagination, but not filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your `get_json_response` produces items, but they completely omit the filtering, ordering and pagination logic, as you can see in the [original implementation <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/clearcare/django-datatables-view/blob/50c035e77c1a191be338bf0d2359e8989ea3925d/django_datatables_view/base_datatable_view.py#L102-L113).

You will thus have to reimplement that yourself:

```
class MyModelDatatable(BaseDatatableView):
    model = MyModel
    columns = ['field1', 'field2', 'id']
    columns_searched = [col for col in columns if col != 'id']

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        print('test')
        search_text = self.request.GET.get('search[value]', None)
        if search_text:
            search_terms = search_text.split()
            query = Q()
            for col in self.columns_searched:
                or_conditions = Q()
                for term in search_terms:
                    or_conditions |= Q(**{f'{col}__icontains': term})
                query |= or_conditions
            qs = qs.filter(query)
        return qs

    def prepare_results(self, qs):
        data = []
        for item in qs:
            item_str = str(item)
            data.append(
                {'field1': item_str, 'field2': item.field2, 'id': item.id}
            )
        return data

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'field2':
            return row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        return super(OrderDatatable, self).render_column(row, column)

    def paging(self, qs):
        start = int(self.request.GET.get('start', 0))
        length = int(self.request.GET.get('length', 10))
        return qs[start : start + length]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_json_response()

    def get_json_response(self):
        draw = int(self.request.GET.get('draw', 1))
        qs = self.get_initial_queryset()
        total_records = qs.count()
        qs = self.filter_queryset(qs)
        total_display_records = qs.count()
        qs = self.ordering(qs)
        qs = self.paging(qs)
        response = {
            'draw': draw,
            'recordsTotal': total_records,
            'recordsFiltered': total_display_records,
            'data': data,
        }
        return JsonResponse(response)
```

I'm however not really following why you are here implementing the entire logic again. This is almost equivalent to the original. So just by overriding the `paging` method, and some others, you let the `BaseDatatableView` view handle the logic. It will return a `JsonResponse` anway, so you are reimplementing boilerplate code.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, I managed to solve the problem.
Thanks also for your valuable advice.